# React.js - how can i pass a state variable + a function defined in a component, to components deep inside map functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

i have here a component,

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const toggleState = (id) => {
    setState(); //setting some stuff
  };

  const list = data.map((datas) => (
    <ComponentOne>
      {datas.children === undefined ? (
        <ComponentTwo>Not Found</ComponentTwo>
      ) : (
        datas.children.map((datasTwo) => (
          <ComponentTwo state={state} toggleState={toggleState}>
            Found
          </ComponentTwo>
        ))
      )}
    </ComponentOne>
  ));

  return <>{list}</>;
};
```

1. in that component im returning a variable that consist of a `<ComponentOne />` that im looping  through with the map function
2. inside of that `<ComponentOne />` i also have a ternary to check if something is defined or not,
3. if its defined, i am going to map another component, which is `<ComponentTwo />`
4. in `<ComponentTwo />` i have props defined for `state` and `toggleState` from `<ParentComponent />`

if i then run the code, there will be an `Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR playButtonState is undefined`

**But**, if i do only one map like this,

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const toggleState = (id) => {
    setState(); //setting some stuff
  };

  const list = data.map((datas) => (
    <ComponentTwo state={state} toggleState={toggleState}>
     found
    </ComponentTwo>
  ));

  return <>{list}</>;
};
```

no ones throwing me an error, thoughts?

Comment: For every child component you have to keep passing the state down in the props.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question doesn't provide enough information about your problem, but it seems that inside of your `ComponentTwo` component, you're assigning the `state` prop to a variable called `playButtonState` and you're using it somewhere that causes the `undefined` error.
Based on that assumption, when the `datas.children === undefined` condition is `true`, you are returning the `<ComponentTwo>Not Found</ComponentTwo>`, so the value of `state` prop is `undefined` and you get the error, so you should take a look at the `ComponentTwo` component and add a couple of `if` statements or something else to control the situation that the `playButtonState` is `undefined`